# Probability Density function of a continuous Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Question: The probability density function of a continuous random variable x is given by f(x)=\begin{cases}3e^{-x} & : x> 0 \\ 0 & : {x\leq0}\end{cases} Which of the following would be the probability that x lies between 1 and 2?

A. $e^{-3}-e^{-6}$

B. $e^{-6}-e^{-3}$

C. 9($e^{-6}-e^{-3}$)

D. 9($e^{-3}-e^{-6}$)

I am asking this question since it was asked in one of the exams and the correct answer given is A i.e. $e^{-3}-e^{-6}$

I tried to solve the question using,

(a). I know that for a continuous random variable x, the probability density function f(x) is such that $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = 1 $.

But here in this question, $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty 3e^{-x}dx = 3 $

(b).To calculate the probability that x lies between 1 and 2, i used $ \int_1^2 3e^{-x}dx = 3(e^{-1}-e^{-2}) $

So,

A. Is this a valid pdf function, Should it not be $3e^{-3x}$ instead of $3e^{-x}$?

B. If it is a valid pdf function, then will the probability not be as I calculated and there will be no correct answer among the options?

Comment: Read here about [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) to typeset your math equations in future.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a valid PDF for the reason you mentioned. Apparently, it should be $3e^{-3x}$, because the standard template for exponential distribution with parameter $\theta$ is $f(x)=\theta e^{-\theta x},x>0$ and $0$ otherwise.

In which case $P(1<X<2)=\displaystyle 3\int_1^2e^{-3x}dx=e^{-3}-e^{-6}$.